# Why I can not launch Java application after codesigning with --option runtime

Tags: java, macos, maven, code-signing

I am destributing Java application for Mac OS, and using appbundler for building the application. It is necessary to notarize application for now, also necessary is to enable Hardened Runtime to pass the notarization. There are some problems about this:

- If I codesign the application without `--option runtime` it works, but can't pass notarization
- If I codesign the application with `--option runtime` it can pass notarization, but can't be launched.

Building app with Maven:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${organization.name}-${version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.panayotis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appbundler</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <mkdir dir="${build.directory}/${build.finalName}"/>
                            <taskdef name="bundleapp" classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"/>
                            <bundleapp outputdirectory="${build.directory}/${build.finalName}"
                                       name="${organization.name}"
                                       displayname="${organization.name}"
                                       identifier="com.company.product"
                                       shortversion="${revision}"
                                       icon="src/main/resources/icons/Icon.icns"
                                       mainclassname="org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
                                       copyright="2019 Company">
                                <runtime dir="${project.basedir}/../misc/jdk-11.0.4+11/Contents/Home"/>
                                <classpath file="${build.directory}/${organization.name}-${revision}.jar"/>
                                <option value="-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:./application.yml"/>
                                <option value="-Djava.awt.headless=false"/>
                                <option value="-Xmx512m"/>
                            </bundleapp>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Codesigning flow:

```sh
codesign --options runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign "Dev. ID" App.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk-11.0.4+11
find "App.app/Contents/Resources/additional executables" -type -f -exec "codesign --options runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign "Dev. ID" {}"
codesign --options runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign "Dev. ID" App.app/Contents/Java/App.jar
codesign --options runtime --entitlements entitlements.plist --sign "Dev. ID" App.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaAppLauncher
```

Entitlements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-executable-page-protection</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Error on launching application from terminal:

```
2019-08-08 10:28:51.443 JavaAppLauncher[4526:559342] int launch(char *, int, char **) Launchpath: /Applications/App.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk-11.0.4+11/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib
2019-08-08 10:28:51.449 JavaAppLauncher[4526:559342] int launch(char *, int, char **) Error launching JVM Runtime (jdk-11.0.4+11) Relative Path: '/Applications/App.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk-11.0.4+11' (dylib: /Applications/App.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk-11.0.4+11/Contents/Home/lib/jli/libjli.dylib)
  error: JRELoadError
```

Comment: I have the very same issue.Did you make progress? Are you using the AdoptOpenJDK? Did you try the newest release?

Comment: Yes, I am using Adopt, but JRE, version 11.0.4+11. It works good. What problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right decision is to get rid of appbundler plugin.
I've wrote my own launcher, built it with X-Code with enabled hardened runtime, and it works perfectly.